# Detect Input Requests from System.in (stdin) in Java Program

Tags: java, redirect, input, inputstream, system.in

I am looking to create a small program where by I would execute some code and when I execute that code which will be outputting data and requesting data through `System.in`, I would like to detect that request and show a text area where the use will enter the data there instead since they will not have access to the terminal.

I have the output part covered in which I will use an OutputStream to redirect `System.out` and `System.err` but could someone explain to me any possibilities for redirecting/detecting System.in requests?

Or is there some sort of SWING Console component that I can use to execute some code and have all output and input be redirected to the component?

Comment: [`System.setIn()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#setIn(java.io.InputStream))?

Comment: GUI? Console? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Console. I'm don't know how to detect input requests, if it is possible. Or is there is some way to execute code in a console like component.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn What I am trying to do is detect the request or have the request be redirected to a Console like component.

Comment: Use a [PipedInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PipedinputStream.html).